# Spring boot REST application deployed as WAR on tomcat is not working

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, tomcat

Created a spring boot REST application.

**Run as Spring boot app**
While running it as `spring boot application` in eclipse. It's working great.
REST API are working with the URL -  `http://localhost:8080/schools`

**Deploy as WAR on tomcat**

I followed the following steps

1. Main class extends `SpringServletContainerInitializer`

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class RmsBackendApplication extends SpringServletContainerInitializer {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(RmsBackendApplication.class, args);
        }
    }
```

2. Added start class entry in `pom.xml`

```
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <start-class>com.codingParkFun.rmsbackend.RmsBackendApplication</start-class>
    </properties>
```

3. Added starter tomcat dependency

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

4. Few documents say override `configure` method of `SpringServletContainerInitializer`. But in my case `SpringServletContainerInitializer` doesn't have a `configure` method. I downloaded spring tools 4.0
5. Generated package with `maven install`. War package is generated with the name `rms-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war`
6. Deployed the war package on the tomcat (version `9.0.27` )
7. Accessing REST API URL - `http://localhost:8080/rms-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/schools`

Output 
[image]

8. Tomcat localhost logs are as follow :

```
09-Nov-2019 11:13:31.013 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log 1 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
09-Nov-2019 11:13:32.048 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextInitialized()
09-Nov-2019 11:13:32.048 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextInitialized()
09-Nov-2019 11:13:32.052 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: attributeAdded('StockTicker', 'async.Stockticker@6231bb88')
09-Nov-2019 11:16:44.566 INFO [Thread-4] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextDestroyed()
09-Nov-2019 11:16:44.566 INFO [Thread-4] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextDestroyed()
09-Nov-2019 11:19:59.676 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log 1 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
09-Nov-2019 11:20:12.722 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextInitialized()
09-Nov-2019 11:20:12.723 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextInitialized()
09-Nov-2019 11:20:12.728 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: attributeAdded('StockTicker', 'async.Stockticker@2420e962')
09-Nov-2019 11:27:44.515 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log 1 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
09-Nov-2019 11:27:45.490 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextInitialized()
09-Nov-2019 11:27:45.490 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextInitialized()
09-Nov-2019 11:27:45.494 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: attributeAdded('StockTicker', 'async.Stockticker@1c7da28')
09-Nov-2019 11:38:48.705 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log 1 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
```

Not sure while the application REST API is not working. Please guide.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to extend **SpringBootServletInitializer**, not **SpringServletContainerInitializer**. Then you can override configure method as you say in step 4, like this:

```
@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(RmsBackendApplication.class);
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I haven't noticed that.

Comment: is adding a start class entry in the pom required? I have not seen this step in any of the online materials - @pepevalbe

Comment: No it is not. These are the steps: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.traditional-deployment